# Efficiently find last date in few table - Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

Hello_ So, I have a few table in teradata
I try to found last report_date in each table

Now I do this like:

```
SELECT 
        'Tablename1'  AS table_name,
        MAX(report_date) report_date
        FROM PRD.tablenamt1
        WHERE REPORT_DATE > CURRENT_DATE-5
    UNION ALL
 SELECT 
        'Tablename2'  AS table_name,
        MAX(report_date) report_date
        FROM PRD.tablenamt2
        WHERE REPORT_DATE > CURRENT_DATE-5
```

Does better way exist? I have many table in which I want to see last report_day

Comment: No reason to replace that.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative could be:

```
create table counts_table ( table_name varchar(100), max_date date);

CREATE PROCEDURE get_max_date (in_object VARCHAR(100), in_date_col VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
  CALL Dbc.SysExecSql('insert into counts_table select ''' || in_object 
    || ''', max(' || in_date_col || ') from ' || in_object);
END;

-- and this is how you run different tables with different date columns
Call get_max_date('PRD.tablenamt1','report_date');
Call get_max_date('PRD.tablenamt2','report_date');

...
select * from counts_table;
```